# Unitary base transformation applied to continous bases

Tags: quantum-mechanics, linear-algebra

For discrete vector spaces one can define a unitary base transformation between two complete orthogonal bases $\{ | b_k \rangle \}$  and $ \{ | a_k \rangle \}$ as
$$U = \sum \limits_k | b_k \rangle \langle a_k|$$

But how can this be applied to continous bases linke $|x\rangle$ and $|p\rangle$ or is this not possible?

Comment: It is not possible, for the continuous bases are not in an Hilbert space.

Comment: oh that is too bad^^